# Error:(45) Error: The <supports-screens> element must be a direct child of the <manifest> root element [WrongManifestParent]

Tags: android

I'm trying to fix this error but I do not fully understand what is wrong. It runs well on the emulator but starts giving me a problem when I'm trying to do a signed apk.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.ntokozo.taxicalculator">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SMS_DELIVER_ACTION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".Logo">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <supports-screens android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="320" />

    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either delete this line:

```
<supports-screens android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="320" />
```

Or move it *outside* of `<activity>`, so it is a direct child of the root `<manifest>` element:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">

</activity>
<supports-screens android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="320" />
```